# What two numbers, not multiples of ten, when multiplied together give a number with at least two trailing zeros?

Tags: number-theory

Lets X , Y and Z are three integers such that X * Y = Z where X and Y are not multiple of 10 and Z is multiple of 100. Then what is the values of X, Y and Z.

Comment: Have you at least found a few examples of such numbers to get an idea of what they might look like?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question.

Answer (score 3):

$Z$ being a multiple of 100 implies that
$$Z = 2\cdot2\cdot5\cdot5\cdot k,$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

You need to distribute those factors (including the prime decomposition of $k$) among $X$ and $Y$. Note that there cannot be a 2 and a 5 at the same time in the prime decomposition of any of them...

Answer (score 2):

$$100 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 = 2^2 \cdot 5^2$$

Let $x$ and $y$ be numbers such that $100|xy$. Now, if $2|x \land 5|x \implies 10|x$ and so $x$ is a multiple of $10$ which we don't want. The same applies for $y$. So, we need an $x$ such that $4|x$ and a $y$ such that $25|y$. Then $100|xy$. Another observation is that if this must happen then $\gcd(x, y) = 1$.